# Python - offset after converting datetime object to s since epoch in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am converting some timestamps like:

```
tmp['start'] = tmp['chargingstart'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timestamp())
```

which I thought would work. I am expecting positive integers, but instead I check with

```
tmp.loc[(tmp['start']) < 0][['chargingstart', 'start']]
```

and I get

```
        chargingstart           start
50053   1970-01-01 00:00:48+00  -3552.0
278149  1970-01-01 00:00:17+00  -3583.0
278150  1970-01-01 00:00:16+00  -3584.0
278152  1970-01-01 00:00:17+00  -3583.0
278153  1970-01-01 00:00:17+00  -3583.0
... ... ...
1590705 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00  -3600.0
1590978 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00  -3600.0
1591012 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00  -3600.0
1702854 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00  -3600.0
1772270 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00  -3600.0
```

I can not figure out, why I get the offset. Any hint?

EDIT: If I do the same in two steps, it seems to work. Why is that?

```
tmp['convertToDtObject'] = tmp['chargingstart'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:19], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
tmp['start'] = tmp['convertToDtObject'].apply(lambda x: x.timestamp())
tmp.loc[(tmp['start']) < 0][['chargingstart', 'convertToDtObject', 'start']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are in UTC timezone, your format string does not seem to be tz-aware. I get the correct answer if I use the following:

```
In [33]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [34]: parse('1970-01-01 00:00:48+00')
Out[34]: datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 48, tzinfo=tzutc())

In [35]: parse(s).timestamp()
Out[35]: 48.0
```